# I can't run python file interactivly with terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I'm using OSX Mac terminal to run python 2.7.10.

for example:

I have a file called "myfile.py"

so when I want to run it on the terminal it would be like this:

```
python Desktop/myfile.py
```

However inside the file I have wrote some functions like

```
def myFunction(x,y):
    return float(x)/y
```

with this method of running a python script I can not interact with my program and use myFunction to input x and y with different values every time and test myFunction properly.

Thank You,

Comment: where are you calling your `myFunction`?

Comment: I want to call it inside the terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can use `python -i script.py`

This way, script.py is executed and then python enter interactive mode. In interactive mode you can use all functions, classes and variables that was defined in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `-i` before the script name

```
python -i myfile.py
```

You can learn more about what options are available by running `man python`.

To quote from the manual:

```
   -i     When a script is passed as first argument or the -c  option
          is  used, enter interactive mode after executing the script
          or the command.  It does not read the $PYTHONSTARTUP  file.
          This  can  be useful to inspect global variables or a stack
          trace when a script raises an exception.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw_input() to do that.
Your myfile.py code can look like this:

```
def myFunction(x,y):
    return float(x)/y

x = raw_input("Please enter x value: ")
y = raw_input("Please enter y value: ")
print(myFunction(x,y))
```